# How can I populate a form in angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms

I have a form application.html which I am using for creating application xml. Now I am reusing the same form for editing the application.
Here is my approach:

There is a form aplication.html and its tabs.js file.
application.html contains input fields etc.

tabs.js looks like:

```
    app.controller('RegisterCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
            $scope.inputLocation = '';
            $scope.form = {
                appName: ' ',
                appOwnerEmail: '',
                feedFileType: '',
                feedFileLocation: '',
                inputType: 'csv',
                validationDetails: [{
                    feedFileName: '',
                    dataTypes: '',
                    skipLinesFromTop: '',
                    skipLinesFromBottom: '',
                    headerRowsNumbers: ''
                }]
            };
 // this function is still incomplete, I need the logic here to populate  
    $scope.populateValues = function(appName,form){
                alert(appName);

                $scope.form.appOwnerEmail = 'gaurav@gmail.com';
                console.log($scope.form.appOwnerEmail);
            };      
    });
```

There is another file EditApplication.html and its selectApp.js file
In EditApplication, there is a drop down menu to select the application and a button "Edit".

When we click on the button, it will include the application.html form and it will be displayed.

```
<div ng-controller="RegisterCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="selectApp">
        <h4 ng-show="displayValue.selectAppPage == 'true'">Select and Edit the Application</h4>

        <div class="well container" ng-show="displayValue.selectAppPage == 'true'">
            <div class="row pager pull-center">
                <div class="span11">
                    <label class="control-label" for="selecttheApplication">Select the Application</label>

                    <select id="selectApplication" ng-model="fileData.selectApplication"
                    ng-options="option for option in fileData.availableOptions"
                    class="selectpicker">
                        <option value="" selected="selected">Select Option</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pager pull-right">
                <input type="button" class="btn" value="Cancel"
                />
                <input type="button" class="btn" value="Edit"
                ng-click="editApp()" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="displayValue.editPage == 'true'"
        ng-switch on="fileType">
            <div ng-switch-when="csv">
                <div ng-include="'application.html'"
                ng-init="populateValues(fileData.selectApplication,form)"></div>
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="text">
                <div ng-include="'runApplication.html'"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

selectApp.js looks like:

```
angular.module("routedTabs").controller("selectApp", function($scope,$http){        
    $scope.displayValue = {
            editPage:'false',           
            selectAppPage:'true'
    };
//edit application scope
    $scope.editApp = function(){    
        alert("All is well!");
        $scope.fileType = 'csv';            
        $scope.toggleDisplay();         
    };
```

Now when I am assigning any value to form's attribute in populateValues() function, it is not visible in the application.html form. 
Am I doing something wrong or missing something? As I am not getting any error.